# lenovo a6000 plus on/off switch not responding

Tags: lenovo-a6000-plus

I have a problem with my Lenovo A6000 plus. when I lock it and a few seconds later I want to open it does not happen any response. and when i plug the charge was no response at all. does not charge the battery, does not respond to its on / off switch, and clock becomes delay. I've replaced the switch on / off with the original one. but still have the same problem. whether there is a solution or any answer what is the problem on my phone?